# Obtaining libc function name (e.g., scanf) with Intel PIN Instrumentation

Tags: c++, trace, instrumentation, intel-pin

I'm trying to obtain a routine name for libc functions (e.g., `scanf` in this case) with the Intel PIN instrumentation. After trying a lot of ways, I am under the belief that this is difficult, but I figured to ask first.

For the sake of brevity, below is a minimal example of an input binary source code and Intel PIN instrumentation code of what I have tried, I feel that the result is close, yet missing the final detail.

Example source code (`test.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(char *buffer) {
    scanf("%s", buffer);
    printf("Unsafe gets: %s\n", buffer);
    
}

int main() {
    char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
    foo(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Intel PIN instrumentation source code (`test_pin.so`):

```
VOID do_call(ADDRINT addr)
{
    printf("%p - %s\n", (void*)addr,  RTN_FindNameByAddress(addr).c_str());
    //fprintf(trace, "\n[%s]\n",  RTN_FindNameByAddress(addr).c_str())); 
    //fflush(trace);
}

VOID Instruction(INS ins, VOID *v)
{
    if (INS_IsCall(ins))
    {
        if (INS_IsDirectBranchOrCall(ins))
        {
            const ADDRINT addr = INS_DirectBranchOrCallTargetAddress(ins);
            INS_InsertPredicatedCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, AFUNPTR(do_call),
                IARG_PTR, addr, IARG_FUNCARG_CALLSITE_VALUE, 0, IARG_END);

        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* initialize symbol processing */
    PIN_InitSymbols();
    /* initialize Pin; optimized branch */
    if (unlikely(PIN_Init(argc, argv)))
        /* Pin initialization failed */
        goto err;
    INS_AddInstrumentFunction(Instruction, 0);

    /* start Pin */
    PIN_StartProgram();

    /* typically not reached; make the compiler happy */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So the reason why I'm saying that I feel somewhat close is that running the above Intel PIN Instrumentation using the command `pin -t test_pin.so -- ./test` will result in the following output:

```
...
0x7f27aac14280 - brk                         
0x7f27aac142e0 - sbrk                        
0x7f27aab97a70 - pthread_attr_setschedparam
0x55a6dcbb8189 - foo                         
0x55a6dcbb8090 - .plt.sec           
0x7f27aab63a00 - psiginfo           
0x7f27aab91c30 - __uflow            
0x7f27aab91e80 - _IO_doallocbuf
...
```

where we can observe that two addresses start with `0x5` (to indicate that this is from the main application rather than calling from a shared library such as `0x7`):

- `0x55a6dcbb8189 - foo`
- `0x55a6dcbb8090 - .plt.sec`

Doing additional investigation using `objdump` or `gdb` of the above source code example, it can be found that the entry address of `foo` function and the mystery target of `.plt.sec` from the Intel PIN is (after removing the relocation base address):

```
0000000000001189 <foo>:    
   ...
 11ac:       e8 df fe ff ff          call   1090 <__isoc99_scanf@plt>
```

So instead of getting the output of `.plt.sec`, is it possible to somehow resolve this mysterious `.plt.sec` name into `__isoc99_scanf`? I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=glibc-debuginfo

Comment: Thank you for your reply @HansPassant I think that is probably the right direction, although I could not spend enough time to apply it on my PIN instrumentation. For those who might be curious, how I managed to solve this issue was to figure out the offset address using `IMG_LoadOffset` command and then use that to calculate the function address, which can be reverse-engineered using programs such as `radare2`.